# Too slow inserting value in cells

Tags: performance, excel, vba

I've created an vba code that works fine except for the following lines:

```
Workbooks("file.xlsm").Worksheets(sheet1).Range("V" & I).Value = ComboBox1.Value
TextBox14.Value = Workbooks("file.xlsm").Worksheets(sheet1).Range("AB" & I).Value
```

The first line insert the value of a combobox in one cell. When doing this, there's another cell in the same row which changes its value. The second line inserts the value of this cell in a textbox.
The problem is that sometimes it takes too many time in inserting the value of the combobox in the cell and the textbox value shows the old value. I don't know how to make that the textbox waits until the cell is updated.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: not sure, but can you try adding `DoEvents` between those two(2)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Force recalculation of the sheet

```
Workbooks("file.xlsm").Worksheets(Sheet1).Range("V" & I).Value = ComboBox1.Value
Workbooks("file.xlsm").Worksheets(Sheet1).Calculate
TextBox14.Value = Workbooks("file.xlsm").Worksheets(Sheet1).Range("AB" & I).Value
```